# Format string using given pattern and delimeter in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, regex, string, postgresql, substring

I am trying to write a PostgreSQL query for below scenario:

Input:
I) alphanumeric string, e.g. `abcd1234efgh`
II) pattern, e.g. `[1][2][3][2][1][3]`
III) delimiter, e.g `-` (hyphen)

Output:
`a-bc-d12-34-e-fgh`

I require a query. Function won't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use one [`regexp_replace()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) call:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('abcd1234efgh'
                     ,'^(.)(..)(...)(..)(.)(...)'
                     ,'\1-\2-\3-\4-\5-\6'
                     )
```

Produces the requested result.

The same written with numbers:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('abcd1234efgh'
                     ,'^(.{1})(.{2})(.{3})(.{2})(.{1})(.{3})'
                     ,'\1-\2-\3-\4-\5-\6'
                     )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat_ws('-',
    left(a, 1),
    substring(a from 2 for 2),
    substring(a from 4 for 3),
    substring(a from 7 for 2),
    substring(a from 9 for 1),
    right(a, 3)
)
from (values ('abcd1234efgh')) s(a)
```

The `concat_ws` function will use its first argument as a separator.